# How to Add Python Directories to Path Using pyproject.toml in a Project Structure with Poetry

Tags: python, import, directory, subdirectory, pyproject.toml

I have a project with the following directory structure:

```
main_directory/
├── main.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── src/
    └── API/
        ├── fileA.py
        └── fileB.py
```

In this structure, `fileA.py` imports `fileB.py`, and `main.py` imports `fileA.py`.

I want to make sure that the Python interpreter recognizes `src/API` and its subdirectories as packages and adds them to the Python path. How can I achieve this without using Poetry or other package managers?

My goal is to ensure that all the scripts in the project, including `main.py` and `fileA.py`, can import modules from `src/API` without any `ModuleNotFoundError` issues. What changes do I need to make in my `pyproject.toml` or any other configuration files to achieve this?

Comment: How does your `pyproject.toml` look like currently?